# How do I use HTTPS between a GKE Ingress and the Service it forwards to?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, https, google-kubernetes-engine

On Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) you can use the `cloud.google.com/app-protocols` annotation on a Service to specify what protocol is used on that port (HTTP or HTTPS) [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#https_tls_between_load_balancer_and_your_application)

When you create an External HTTP(S) Ingress, it will use this protocol between the Ingress and the Service.

How do I set things up so that the Service uses a certificate that is actually trusted by the Ingress?

Does it just trust any certificate signed by the [Cluster Root CA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust)? [Manage tls in a cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#create-a-certificate-signing-request) suggests you need to include the pod IP address in the CSR - does that mean generating the CSR and waiting for the signed certificate to be created should be part of my container startup process?

Comment: do you have your own certificate or you use Google managed one?

Comment: For the external interface I used my own certificate. For the communication between the Ingress and the Service I'm open to either using my own certificate or a Google-managed one (but reading the docs I got the impression that Google-managed certificates are meant for external endpoints, not for internal communication?)

Comment: Have you tested using your own certificate? In this case I think your pod should be able to validate the certificate using an internal CA. I will try to work on it and come back asap. Btw, do you have any certificate in your pod?

Comment: I figured it out: it does not need any CA at all, it does not check the certificate and will happily connect to a service using a self-signed certificate without further configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when the "GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing" uses HTTPS to connect to the service, it accepts *any* certificate valid (even a self-signed one), without further configuration.

Apparently it does not use TLS to protect against MITM attacks here (which I guess might be reasonable).